# How to set an Alarm Using an Intent Selecting the full date of the alarm (including day, month)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarmmanager

So I'm trying to add a feature in my app to launch the alarm clock and set one, I tried it using the usual code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM); 
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "New Alarm");  
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 10);  
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, 30);  
startActivity(i);
```

And it worked fine, the only issue is that the AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR param can be from 0 to 24 meaning I will be setting an alarm at best in the next 24 hours, but let's say I'm on Monday and I want to set an alarm on Friday, is there any way to do it?

I went over the AlarmClock documentation on Android Developers and found only the following optional params:

> EXTRA_HOUR (optional): The hour of the alarm being set.
>
> EXTRA_MINUTES (optional): The minutes of the alarm being set.
>
> EXTRA_DAYS (optional): Weekdays for repeating alarm.
>
> EXTRA_MESSAGE (optional): A custom message for the alarm.
>
> EXTRA_RINGTONE (optional): A ringtone to play with this alarm.
>
> EXTRA_VIBRATE (optional): Whether or not to activate the device
>   vibrator for this alarm.
>
> EXTRA_SKIP_UI (optional): Whether or not to display an activity for
>   setting this alarm.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `EXTRA_DAYS` and enable the alarm only on the day (or days) you want it. This creates a repeating alarm, so you'll need to cancel it after it gets triggered if you don't want it to repeat.

Comment: so if im on Tuesday and I want the alarm on Next Monday you suggest I put an alarm for EVERY Monday and once Monday is here I turn it off?

Comment: yes, That's what you could do with the `AlarmClock` API that is available. Otherwise you need to schedule an alarm with `AlarmManager` and have it start your own `Activity` or whatever...

Comment: Alright, I will be checking how the AlarmManager works. Thanks for the help!